# Is wearing weight adders on arms beneficial?

Tags: exercise, strength, exercise-equipment

I am doing weight-lifting 3 times a week, 2-3 hours for each workout.

Now I got a gift of arm weight adders (basically, a sand bag wrapped around forearm, each bag weights 1kg). I'm considering wearing them at home, during my everyday activities, to give my arms some extra training (seems the biceps will get the biggest impact).

Will that improve my training results or will it simply lead to overtraining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are light enough not to cause over-training, unless you are an advanced lifter.  However, they provide stresses on your joints that are not natural.  Depending on what you are doing and how forcefully you are moving, they can cause damage  to your elbow and shoulder joints or force a stretch you aren't ready for.

I had a Sensei who trained with those things on hands and feet against his Sensei's advice.  After many years of the added stress on his joints (punching and kicking), he had to have both his hips replaced.

If all you are doing is making coffee in the morning with those things, you'll probably be OK.  Just be careful if you get the bright idea to do anything that requires force or quick movements.

Answer (score 1):

No you will not experience over-training. What you may experience is fatigue though.

I do not believe they will cause damage despite what others may say. I find many people complain about how deteriorated their body is and get unnecessary surgeries when there was nothing wrong with them in the first place besides aches and pains from physical exertion. I know for a fact that bones, tendons, vessels, nerves, and so forth can be in pain from training and some people just go "crazy" from it. Really.

With that in mind go ahead and take it easy with excessive ballistic movements until you've worn the weights daily for a couple months.

I am currently wearing 10 lb ankle weights, 5 lb wrist weights, and a 32 lb weight vest. I don't walk long distances but I move around throughout the day. I sleep with them on.

Avoid ballistic movements until you have worn them for over a month and you will not experience much pain or discomfort. Your arms and shoulders may grow if you wear them ever day all day and increase the weight or start punching the air with them on. It's not a waste of time either way as it will always help to have a 24/7 resistance component in your training.